# How to use .htaccess to redirect missing files?

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I've been hosting some files which aren't on the server anymore and apache error log keeps bugging me with the "file does not exist" line.

I'd like to use .htaccess to **manually** specify which files, if requested in the URI, should redirect to the root location (or any else, thereof).

Could anyone help me how to do that?

Example:

`www.domain.com/non-existent-file.jpg` should go to `www.domain.com/`

Comment: Not a good idea. To throw 404 is important for search-engines... Otherwise you' ll get a lot of 'dead links'

Comment: @ChristianGärtner: Can I properly throw 404 and make apache **not** log the file into error log?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it with:

```
RewriteRule non-existent-file.jpg http://www.domain.com/ [R=301]
```

Hope that's the best solution!